# Iterating over certain model attributes with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm learning tests in Rails with RSpec and I'm trying to refactor some basic unit tests.

I have a model with :name, :protein and :calories. I would like to write a .each do loop that would loop only through some of the attributes (:protein and :calories), set a negative value to them and then test them.

Right now I'm writing duplicate code

```
  it "is not valid with negative values" do
    subject.calories = -1
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end

  it "is not valid with negative values" do
    subject.protein = -1
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end
```

As there are actually several attributes I would like to be able to write something like

```
nutritional_value = [:protein, :calories]
  nutritional_value.each do |nutr|
    subject.nutr = -1
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end
```

Hope I've made myself clear, still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what your model attributes are (can you post them?) but if your model has the fields "protein" and "calories" and you validate these to be > -1 you probably want to:

```
  [:protein, :calories].each do |nutr|
    subject[nutr] = -1
    expect(subject).to_not be_valid
  end
```

Also if you have two different validations defined in your model, it's better practice to spec them in two separate examples if you absolutely want to do it by the book.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is not best practices to write logic in spec file.
Install shoulda matchers gem (https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers)
And then you can write like this

```
it { is_expected.not_to allow_value(-1).for(:protein) }
it { is_expected.not_to allow_value(-1).for(:calories) }
```